# Mongodb not working synonym

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a beginner in mongodb. I have some issue :

```
      checkmongo.competition_user.find({"userid": parseInt(data.uid), "status": 1}, function(err, res) {
        if (err || !res)
            callback('failed to save');
        else {

            checkmongo.chat_message.find({"competition_id":res.competitionid}).limit(1).sort({create_date: -1}, function(err, saved) {

                if (err || !saved)
                    callback('failed to save');
                else {
                    callback(saved[0]);
                }
            });
            callback(res);
        }
    });
```

I want all competition user list and latest message detail in a single object.This is not working. I want JSon like this:

```
    [
    {
        "_id": "564c757ce5c5487692fd3ada",
        "competition_name": "Leage 2015",
        "competitionid": 164,
        "joined_date": "2015-11-18T12:56:28.214Z",
        "status": 1,
        "userid": 1,
        "messsage":"Hi this is my first message"

    },
    {
        "_id": "564c7974e5c54876b508f7f2",
        "competition_name": "World cup leage",
        "competitionid": 167,
        "joined_date": "2015-11-18T13:13:24.200Z",
        "status": 1,
        "userid": 1,
        "messsage":"Hi this is my second message"
    }   
]
```

Any body can get collection link here : 
[Collection here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyy9sqfqq71gk9k/mongo-tipsterchat-20151214-114913.js?dl=0)

Comment: Please detail on your problem. 'This is not working' is not going to answer a question.

Comment: I have two collection competition_user and chat_message.. Chat_message have competition id. I want last chat_message according competition id. In MySQL i want join. Example :
First get all competition find according user id and then get latest chat message using completion id in a single object.

Comment: Please add sample documents from your *involved* collections.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyy9sqfqq71gk9k/mongo-tipsterchat-20151214-114913.js?dl=0

Comment: @yogeshkumar - Please update your post with minimal test data insert scripts for the collections, not everyone would have access to links if they are behind firewalls.